# How can I set up a redirect on GKE to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a service deployed on GKE, with a a google cloud external load balancer. I would now like to winddown this service, but initially by redirecting to an app engine service. Is this possible via just the load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [Serverless Network Endpoint Group (NEG)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts).
You can find tutorial on creating such a setup [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless). Certain steps can be skipped since you already have the load balancer configured.